# Authentication problem PostGIS - QGIS

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

I am using PostGIS as the main data storage for QGIS with stored login credentials. This works great, with one exception: For some layers, QGIS starts asking me for login credentials to the QGIS server. This may happen for several layers from the same database connection. As far as I can see, this has happened when a new set of credentials has been stored so that the old one no longer is available. This makes complete sense, but is there any way to update a PostGIS layer to use new stored login credentials?

QGIS 3.26 on Windows 11 at the moment, but I have had the problem for quite a while, PostGIS 3.2 on PostgreSQL 14 running on CentoOS.